# Merge duplicate data without affecting others in LINQ code

Tags: c#, linq

Goal:
If any duplicate, it should be merged into one for instance if "_name: a", _quantity: 3" and "_name: a", _quantity: 6" should be merged into "_name: a", _quantity: 9" in the list with other data with duplicate or not.

Problem:
I have a list with lots of data and I don't know how to merge duplicate data into one unit + it should not affect others. If possible, would like everyting to be happened inte same list without creating more list to acheive the result.

```
List<Sale> myList = GetAllSalesList()


public classs Sale
{
     public string _name;
     public string _quantity;
}
```

Comment: So, for duplicates, are you deleting all but one row and updating the quantity of one row?  Or are you deleting all rows and creating a new one?  Do you have FK constraints that come into play?

Comment: In this context, no database is involved. Yes, somehow you are updating a row + deleting a row from the list.
FK will not be involved

Comment: `_quantity` is a string ? Is that correct ?

Comment: +1 to digEmAll's question - I guess it's an int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
var mergedList = 
myList.GroupBy(x => x._name)
      .Select(g => new Sale{_name = g.Key, _quantity = g.Sum(x => x._quantity)})
      .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

I've just noticed that `_quantity` is a `string`, is that correct ?
If it is, change the piece of code using `Sum()`,  to:

```
g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x._quantity)).ToString()
```

of course if `_quantity` represents an `int`... otherwise use `double` or `decimal` etc...

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by using Grouping

```
var query = from sales in list
            group sale by _name into grouped
            select new Sale
            {
               _name = grouped.Key,
               _quantity = grouped.Sum(x => x._quantity)
            }; 

var groupedList = query.ToList();
```

For more on grouping, please see the practical examples in the 101 page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Note - this answer assumes that _quantity is actually an int and that integer overflow is not a concern

Comment: can you explain `Key` I've never seen that used before.

Comment: LINQ group by creates an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TVal>>`. `Key` is the key of the `IGrouping` object

Comment: Key is the thing you group by when you use "group". Take a look at the examples for Group By - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1 - or try ... hang on I'll find a tutorial!

Comment: This looks like an OK explanation of how to do grouping and how to use Key - http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/08/how-to-use-grouping-in-c-linq-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

```
var aggregateList = 
    myList.GroupBy(i => i._name)
          .Select(g => new Sale
         {
             _name = g.Key, 
             _quantity = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt64(x._quantity)).ToString()
         })
         .ToList();
```